# Finding to which polygon a point belongs - In python

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapefile, shapely

I have a SHP file with polygons (representing neighborhoods) and a CSV file of murders in my city with coordenates of where it happened. I need to find to which neigborhood each murder belongs and register it in the CSV in a new column.

I know its quite easy but i just started programing and for my life i cant do it. I have tried with pandas, geopandas and shapely.
I have tried adding the new data to a df and then appending it to the CSV but no data was added to the DF.
I have tried using gpd.sjoin between the geodataframes but the column always ends up with NaN values.

Comment: Welcome to SO. See how to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a point that exists within a polygon, `gdp.sjoin` is the way to go. See with a minimum example below:

```py
import geopandas
from geodatasets import get_path
from shapely.geometry import  Point

path_to_data = get_path("nybb")
gdf = geopandas.read_file(path_to_data)

# Point inside Manhattan
gdf_pt = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[Point(-73.97, 40.78)],crs = 'EPSG:4326' )
gdf.sjoin(gdf_pt.to_crs(gdf.crs)) # returns Manhattan Boro
```

If you are getting nulls with your `sjoin`,

1. try visualizing the data your points might not exactly lie inside the polygons.
2. make sure you're using the same `crs` for each geometry
3. Try using with `sjoin_nearest` if your points are close to but not inside polygons (But this will require you to experiment with the parameters to fit your usecase)

Comment: Yeah, i wasn't using the same crs. Now i fixed it, but then it broke again

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but IIUC, here is the general logic with a left [`sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html) :

```
murders_locations = gpd.sjoin(murders, nhoods, how="left")
# with an optional chain : `.drop(columns="index_right")`

# uncomment the line below to make a new .csv having a new col `Neighborhood`
# murders_locations.to_csv("murders_locations.csv", index=False)
```

Output :

```
print(murders_locations) # new column ----------------v

   Latitude  Longitude                 geometry Neighborhood
0       2.5        3.0  POINT (3.00000 2.50000)          NaN
1       2.0        1.0  POINT (1.00000 2.00000)       nhood2
2       3.0        0.7  POINT (0.70000 3.00000)          NaN
3       0.3        0.2  POINT (0.20000 0.30000)       nhood1
4       1.6        1.5  POINT (1.50000 1.60000)       nhood2
```

If needed, you can list the safest & most dangerous neighborhoods :

```
safest_hoods = (set(nhoods["Neighborhood"]).difference(
                    murders_locations["Neighborhood"]))
# {nhood3}

most_dangerous_hood = (murders_locations["Neighborhood"]
                    .value_counts().nlargest(1).index[0])
# nhood2
```

You can also visualize the *sjoin* operation :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nhoods.plot(ax=ax, color="lightblue", edgecolor="black", alpha=0.7)

murders_locations.plot(
    ax=ax, color="red", marker="x", lw=3, markersize=60, label="Murders")

for hood, x, y in zip(nhoods["Neighborhood"],
    nhoods.geometry.centroid.x, nhoods.geometry.centroid.y) :
    ax.text(x, y, hood, fontsize=12, ha="center", va="center",
            color="black", alpha=0.5)

plt.legend()
plt.axis("off")
plt.show();
```

[image]

Used inputs :

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

neighborhoods = {
    "nhood1": Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0.2, 1)]),
    "nhood2": Polygon([(0, 2), (1.5, 2.5), (2.2, 1.5), (1.4, 1)]),
    "nhood3": Polygon([(2, 0), (3.4, 0), (3.4, 1.5), (2.6, 1)]),
}

nhoods = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    neighborhoods.items(), columns=["Neighborhood", "geometry"])

# In your configuration, the `csv` DataFrame would be made by `pd.read_csv`
csv = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Latitude": [2.5, 2.0, 3.0, 0.3, 1.6],
     "Longitude": [3, 1.0, 0.7, 0.2, 1.5]})

murders = gpd.GeoDataFrame(csv, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
                csv["Longitude"], csv["Latitude"]))
```

Comment: Good answer, just one suggestion for visualizations with geopandas dataframe, [explore](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html) is another good option especially for lat/long visualization

Comment: Thanks but `explore` would make an interactive map while in my example, I'm not using a CRS.